# Dataframe Mapping exercice

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I just started Python and I block on a simple exercise.
I have 3 Dataframes like bellow :

**df1 :**

```
   A B C         
 0 1 2 3           
 1 4 5 6
```

**df2 (empty) :**

```
   D E F G H
0
1
```

**dfmap :**

```
   m1 m2 m3 m4 m5
0  D  F  H
1  A  B  C
```

I want to write a script which will fill df2 according to the mapping of dfmap.
So the output should be

**df2 :**

```
   D E F G H
0  1   2   3
1  4   5   6
```

I started this code but i guess i miss all the power of Dataframe (and it doesn't work Array_df2 full of nan)
I know it should exist a smartest/simplest way to do that.

```
listcol_df1 = {}
listcol_df2 = {}

for idx, col in enumerate(df1.columns):
    listcol_df1[col] = idx
    
for idx, col in enumerate(df2.columns):
    listcol_df2[col] = idx

Array_df1 = df1.values
Array_df2 = df2.values
Array_dfmap = dfmap.values

for i in range(df1.shape[0]):
    for j in range(dfmap.shape[1]):
        df2[i][listcol_df2.get(Array_dfmap[0][j])] = Array_df1[i][listcol_df1.get(Array_dfmap[1][j])]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dfmap` to rename `df1.columns` and use that to update `ddf2`:

```
df2.update(df1.rename(columns=dfmap.T.set_index(1)[0]))
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
   D   E    F   G    H
0  1 NaN  2.0 NaN  3.0
1  4 NaN  5.0 NaN  6.0
```

Comment: Nice solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alteranative just looping through the columns of `dfmap`, but you may need to add exception handling if `dfmap` contains column names not in the other DFs:

```
for col in dfmap:
    df2[dfmap[col].loc[0]] = df1[dfmap[col].loc[1]]
```

To explain, the loop iterates through the column names in `dfmap`, then this syntax - `dfmap[col].loc[X]` - just selects the column in `dfmap`, followed by the row (`.loc[0]` selects the the value in the first row, `.loc[1]` selects the value in the second row). Now that I think about it, this could also be written perhaps more simply as `dfmap.loc[X, col]` where X is the row number in each case.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works
But I feel guilty because i don't know why it works.

Comment: Have updated my answer with more explanation, hope this helps!